# A proof that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}P''(r_i)/P'(r_i)=0$ for a degree $n$ polynomial

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, summation

Let $P(x)$ be a degree $n$ polynomial with distinct roots $r_1, r_2, \cdots r_n$. Prove that

$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{P''(r_i)}{P'(r_i)}=0$$

My proof: We can equivalently rewrite the polynomial as $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\cdots(x-r_n)$ and if we plug in the roots in the polynomial, we get that all of them are equal to $0$ so their first derivatives are equal to $1$ and then their second derivatives are equal to $0$ which means that all quotients are equal to $0$ and there for the sum is as well, $Q.E.D$

Don't show the solution please, but if you have a hint, feel free. Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify your notation: what is $P''(i)$ and $P'(i)$?

Comment: Your "proof" is wrong.  In most cases, $P'(i)$ are not equal to $1$, and $P''(i)$ are not equal to $0$.  Try an example with $n=3$.

Comment: And I think you mean $P''(r_i)/P'(r_i)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
P''(r_k) = P'(r_k)\sum_{j \ne k}\frac1{r_k-r_j}
$$
plug in, and sum over $k$

Comment: Do you have a proof of that formula?

Comment: @Kurome, If $a$ denotes the leading coefficient of $P(x)$, then $$P'(x)=a\sum_{p} \prod_{i:i\neq p}(x-r_i),\qquad P''(x)=a\sum_{p,q:p\neq q} \prod_{i:i\neq p,q}(x-r_i).$$ Plugging $x=r_k$ thus gives $$P'(r_k)=a\prod_{i:i\neq k}(r_k-r_i),\qquad P''(r_k)=a\sum_{p:p\neq k}\prod_{i:i\neq k,p}(r_k-r_i).$$ Comparing both sides gives $$P''(r_k)=2P'(r_k)\sum_{p:p\neq k}\frac{1}{r_k-r_p}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
$P'(x)$ is a sum of products, in each of which one of the factors $x - r_i$ has been removed.
In $P'(r_i)$, most of those products will be $0$.

Comment: I heard that one could Solve it with induction?

Comment: I got that $P'(r_i)=(r_i-r_1)(r_i-r_2)\cdots(r_i-r_r_i-1)$ and $P''(r_i)=2(r_i-r_1)(r_i-r_2)\cdots(r_i-r_r_i-1)'$